# laravel api using passport to fetch data from product?

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5.6, laravel-passport

Need help to fetch data from product table using sql query in laravel

via laravel passport api authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a route in your api.php

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api', 'throttle:60'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('products', 'Api\ProductController@getProducts');
}
```

Write the getProducts function in your ProductController

```
public function getProducts(){
    return Product::all();
}
```

Send a get request into /api/products with **Authorization** header. Its value will be your access token. Do not forget to add 'Bearer ' before it. (there is space between your access token and Bearer word).

I recommend you to use Postman for this job.

Comment: what is domain ??

Comment: sorry for that, copy paste mistake

Comment: is it possible without auth ?

Comment: if you set your route outside of the auth:api middleware, you dont need to authenticate then

Answer (score 0):

handle access token using laravel passport api authentication.